# Set ContentType on Azure Blob on upload from Javascript using UploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob

Tags: javascript, azure, pdf, content-type, azure-blob-storage

For PDF files to display in the browser - instead of downloading - you need to supply them with the `application/pdf` content type header.

By default, Azure Blob Storage files are set to `application/octet-stream`. The content type can be changed on the back-end by updating it on the blob ... we want to set it at upload time.

Uploading PDF files using the `@azure/storage-blob` ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/?view=azure-node-latest#uploadbrowserdatatoblockblob-aborter--blob---arraybuffer---arraybufferview--blockbloburl--iuploadtoblockbloboptions-)) npm package we cannot find the correct way to set this.

Tried many iterations of the following code to no avail.

```js
...
const blobOptions = {
    metadata: { 'contentType': 'application/pdf' },
    ... other options
};

Azure.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(aborter, file, blob, blobOptions)
...
```

- Note - this can be used to set the correct mime type for anything ... but browsers seem to have no problem converting .jpg, .png etc ... only has issue with .pdf that I have seen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My colleague found an answer:

```
...
const blobOptions = {
    blobHTTPHeaders: { blobContentType: 'application/pdf' },
    ... other options
};

Azure.uploadBrowserDataToBlockBlob(aborter, file, blob, blobOptions)
...
```

and added the `x-ms-blob-content-type` header to Azure storage CORS settings.

Comment: worked first time, thanks for updating with an answer

Comment: worked to open pdf from stream response in angular, thanks !

Comment: I looked at like 6 different methods before finding this and it worked like a charm! Thanks for saving my sanity!